# MySQL extraction query in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi I have this table in my database:

```
id | day | hour
1  | 2   | 17
2  | 2   | 16
3  | 5   | 18
4  | 7   | 24
```

Day would be the day of the week, then:
1 = Monday
2 = Tuesday

etc. Mentre hour it's the hours of the day.

I would like a php page where in this case it would show me:

Tuesday: 17 16
Friday: 18
Sunday: 23

How can I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on asking questions. At least, you need to show what you have tried because SO is not a code-writing site.

Comment: Adding to @Nick's comment: Read about writing good questions over here http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: `group_concat` by day and then on the app layer remove `,`

Comment: I note that Mentre is Italian for While

Comment: Where is `Sunday: 23` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute below query in PHP code and print result in page.

```
    <?php
$q = "SELECT 
  CASE WHEN `day` = 7 then 'Sunday'
    WHEN `day` = 1 then 'Monday'
    WHEN `day` = 2 then 'Tuesday'
    WHEN `day` = 3 then 'Wednesday'
    WHEN `day` = 4 then 'Thursday'
    WHEN `day` = 5 then 'Friday'
    WHEN `day` = 6 then 'Saturday' 
  END AS dayname, 
GROUP_CONCAT(hour) AS hours_grouped 
FROM TABLE-NAME 
GROUP BY `day`";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result=mysqli_query($con,$q);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['dayname'].': '.$row['hours_grouped'].'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: That is the problem with original post. Author is asking *"I would like a php page where in this case it would show me:"*. I mean, techinically your answer is absolutely wrong, since it is not PHP :-) ;-)

Comment: I have mention that, you can execute this query through PHP code and print that result.

Comment: But that is not how SO works. If somebody ask question about PHP  - answer should be about PHP. Your answer is "universal" and MySQL. So yes we can use it in php, node.js, java, python, etc. But question was about php ;-)

Comment: *mysql_fetch_array* - deprecated :-)

Comment: To make it more performant, I would move **day** to **dayname** conversion to php. That way query should become much faster.